# Multiple field for search bar does not work

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search bar with 3 types of input and I want to search into my database if a data exist with those criteria.

Here is my html code for my search bar :

```
   <form method="GET" action="{{ route('admin.liste.article.accueil.article') }}" class="mt-4 background_form">
       <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="inputCity">Rechercher par ...</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="rechercher" type="text" aria-label="Search" value="{{ request()->query('recherche') }}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="inputState">Type article</label>
              <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="type_article">
                  <option></option>
                  @foreach ($type_articles as $type_article)                  
                    <option value="{{ $type_article->type_article_id }}">{{ $type_article->libelle }}</option>
                   @endforeach
                </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-3">
               <label for="datePublication">Date de publicaton</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Exemple : 2021-02-29" name="date" value="{{ request()->query('date') }}">
           </div>
           <div class=" col-md-2 align-self-center mt-3">
              <button type="submit" class="form-control btn-sm btn-custom mb-2">Trouver</button>
            </div>
           </div>
     </form>
```

Into my controller :

```
    public function accueil_article(Request $request)
    {
      $rechercher_par_accueil = $request->query('rechercher');
      $type_article_rechercher_accueil = $request->query('type_article');
      $date_publication_recherche_accueil = $request->query('date');
      if($rechercher_par_accueil || $type_article_rechercher_accueil || $date_publication_recherche_accueil){
          $article_rechercher = Article::where('titre', 'like', "%{$rechercher_par_accueil}%")
            ->when(request()->query('type_article_recherche'), function($query) {
                $query->where('type_article_id', 'like', "%{$type_article_rechercher_accueil}%");
            })
            ->when(request()->query('date_publication_recherche'), function($query) {
                $query->where('created_at', 'like', "%{$date_publication_recherche_accueil}%");
            })
            ->simplePaginate(5);         
      } else {
        $article_rechercher =  Article::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
      }
      return view('admin/article/admin_liste_article', [
        'articles' => $article_rechercher,
        'type_articles' => Type_article::all(),
        'themes' => Theme::all()
       ]);
}
```

And at the bottom of my view, I've :

```
{!! $articles->appends(['rechercher' => request()->query('rechercher'), 'type_article' => request()->query('type_article'), 'date' => request()->query('date')])->links() !!}
```

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
$query->whereIn('type_article_id', [$type_article_rechercher_accueil]);
```

Comment: I should replace `{$array_with_id}` by `"%{$type_article_rechercher_accueil}%"` ?

Comment: That's what I did : https://pastebin.com/h6FB6jiT But still no working. Inside my url bar, the searching name/type of article is well displayed : `http://localhost/admin/liste-article?rechercher=Orange&type_article=3&date=`

Comment: The second parameter of `whereIn()` is an array. Assuming `$type_article_rechercher_accueil = $request->query('type_article');` is an array, it would be

```
$type_article_rechercher_accueil = $request->query('type_article');
...
$query->whereIn('type_article_id', $type_article_rechercher_accueil);
```

Comment: When I replace `"%{$type_article_rechercher_accueil}%"` by `$rechercher_par_accueil` nothing is shown. When I replace this `$rechercher_par_accueil` by `"%{$type_article_rechercher_accueil}%"`, only the `"%{$type_article_rechercher_accueil}%"` result is shown.

Comment: Make sure `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file so you see clear errors. Next, make sure the second argument to `whereIn()` is an array. You may need to wrap it in square brackets like `whereIn('type_article_id', [$type_article_rechercher_accueil])` since it is probably a single string value.

Comment: Still not working, I'll check a solution tomorrow since its 00:00am here. Don't hesitate if you find a solution mate :)